# How to get all updated documents' values after updateMany()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

**Desired Behaviour**

After updating a property value in multiple documents, access the value of that updated property for each document updated.

*(for context, I am incrementing multiple users' notification counts, and then sending each updated value back to the respective user, if they are logged in, via `socket.io`)*

**What I've Tried**

```js
let collection = mongo_client.db("users").collection("users"); 
let filter = { "user_email": { $in: users_to_notify } };
let update = { $inc: { "new_notifications": 1 } };
let result = await collection.updateMany(filter, update);

// get the `new_notifications` value for all updated documents here
```

There doesn't seem to be a `returnOriginal` type `option` applicable to the `updateMany()` method.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany

That is understandable, because `returnOriginal` only seems to make sense when updating one document, eg in the options for the [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) method.

**Question**

If all of the above assumptions are true, what would be the best way to get the `new_notifications` value for all updated documents after the `updateMany()` method has finished?

Is it just a matter of making another database call to get the updated values?

---

*for example - this works:*

```js
let collection = mongo_client.db("users").collection("users"); 
let filter = { "user_email": { $in: users_to_notify } };
let update = { $inc: { "new_notifications": 1 } };
await collection.updateMany(filter, update);

// make another database call to get updated values  
var options = { projection: { user_email: 1, username: 1, new_notifications: 1 } };
let docs = collection.find(filter, options).toArray(); 

/*expected result: 
[{
    "user_email": "user_1@somedomain.com",
    "username": "user_1",
    "new_notifications": 17

},
{
    "user_email": "user_2@somedomain.com",
    "username": "user_2",
    "new_notifications": 5

}]*/  

// create an object where each doc's user_email is a key with the value of new_notifications  
var new_notifications_object = {};

// iterate over docs and add each property and value  
for (let obj of docs) {
        new_notifications_object[obj.user_email] = obj.new_notifications; 
}

/*expected result: 
{
    "user_1@somedomain.com": 17,
    "user_2@somedomain.com": 3  
}*/  

// iterare over logged_in_users
for (let key of Object.keys(logged_in_users)) {

    // get logged in user's email and socket id 
    let user_email = logged_in_users[key].user_email;
    let socket_id = key;

        // if the logged in user's email is in the users_to_notify array
        if (users_to_notify.indexOf(user_email) !== -1) {
            // emit to the socket's personal room  
            let notifications_count = new_notifications_object[user_email]; 
            io.to(socket_id).emit('new_notification', { "notifications_count": notifications_count });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

updateMany() does not return the updated documents but some counts. You have to just run another query for getting those updates.
Would suggest you do a find({}) first, then findByIdAndUpdate() in a loop of the found items.

```
let updatedRecord = [];
let result = await Model.find(query);
if (result.length > 0) {
  result.some(async e => {
    updatedRecord.push(await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(e._id, updateObj, { new: true }));
  });
}
return updatedRecord;
```

Comment: Never use async method in for loop,